# What is $P(a<X<b)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

How can I calculate $P(a<X<b)$?

We can write $P(a<X<b)=P((a<X)\cap (X<b)) $, but $(a<X)$ and  $(X<b)$ are not independent.  I don't know how I should find this probability.

Comment: What information do you have? e.g., do you have $P(a < X)$ and $P(X < b)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(a<X<b) = P((X<b)-(X\leq a)) = P(X<b) - P(X\leq a)$

This might be what you are looking for.

Comment: The use of " $\leq$ " is very important in this case.